# Find Start and End Positions of Word in String JS

Tags: javascript

I have two variables: `string` and `word`. I need to get start and end position of `word` in `string` **if exists**, for example:

```
string = "Hello world"
word = "Hello"
// position = [0, 4]
```

or

```
string = "hello world Hello"
word = "Hello"
// position = [0, 4]
```

I can't figure out a way of planning a function like this, I think there is no built-in function useful in this case, any ideas?

Comment: First instance only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf` and adding the substring length to the index found will get you what you want.

```js
string = "Hello world"
word = "Hello"

const index = string.indexOf(word);
if (index !== -1) {
  const endIndex = index + word.length - 1;
  console.log(index, endIndex);
}
```

If you want `"hello world Hello"` and `"Hello"` to produce `0` and `4`, then it sounds like you need to lower case the string first.

```js
string = "hello world Hello"
word = "Hello"

const index = string.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());
if (index !== -1) {
  const endIndex = index + word.length - 1;
  console.log(index, endIndex);
}
```